# Can "own" stand on its own?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

My gut feeling tells me that sentences such as

> Own mistakes have to be dealt with first.
>
> Own experience matters the most.
>
> We present own results.

are not correct, and I would supplement "own" with, for example, "your" or "my".

Is the above use of "own" just unusual, or is there a general rule saying that "own" always requires the possessive of a noun or a possessive pronoun?

The Oxford dictionary at least [suggests](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/own_1) that "own" cannot be used after an article:

> Own cannot be used after an article:
>
> I need my own room. (Not: I need an own room.)
>
> It's good to have your own room. (Not: It's good to have the own room.)

Are there other words for which that is also the case?

("own" without a pronoun is often found in English texts written by German native speakers, because in German it is perfectly fine to say "Eigene Fehler ...".)

Comment: It doesn't need a possessive *pronoun*: you can say *John's own room.*

Comment: @PeterShor Agreed, but in your example there is a noun, John. Do you know if I can also use "own" at the beginning of a sentence as in the above examples?

Comment: Not in my dialect. They should be *"one's own"* or *"your own"* for the first two sentences, and *"our own"* for the third. The OED has some examples for that, but mainly in regional dialects or with respect to relatives (*an own child, an own cousin, an own daughter*), and they all sound wrong to me. For example, *"I do not think my mother's sisters could have been kinder to me if I had been an own daughter."*

Comment: @PeterShor Is not the point that 'own'is a sort of adjectival suffix which does not work alone e.g. 'Students' own accommodation', 'his own car' etc. I am not sufficiently a grammarian to explain this further, but that is my amateur assessment.  I can however think of one instance where it does stand alone, namely an 'own goal'. But that, presumably, is because it is part of a noun phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the CaGEL, the adjective *own* is unique amongst adjective because it only occurs with a genitive subject-determiner.

A genitive subject-determiner is either:

- a possessive pronoun such as *my, your her* and so forth: my own orangutan
- a genitively inflected Noun Phrase such as John **'s** or Mary **'s**: Mary's axe

There are a very few exception to this rule, but they all occur in fixed phrases such as *an own goal*.

In short we cannot use the adjective *own* without a preceding noun.

[CaGEL is *The Cambridge grammar of the English language* Huddleston and Pullum, 2002]

Answer (score 0):

To find other examples you'd look for other reflexive-like, slightly redundant noun/pronoun modifiers/'emphasizers?' and I can't find/think of any, so to make this an answer (instead of a comment, where it probably belongs, but for which I don't have enough 'reputation') I'll say:

> No, there are no other words for which this is also the case.